# C# - How do I change an Object's type and then use methods from the Class?

Tags: c#, object, typeof

```
public void ChangeObjectType(System.Type objectType, Object selectedObject)
{
    selectedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
}

internal void BuoyToMouse()
{
    ChangeObjectType(typeof(Buoy), selectedObject);
    selectedObject.setPosition(mouseCurrentState.X - mouseStart.X, mouseCurrentState.Y - mouseStart.Y);
}
```

I'm creating a game and I'm trying to handle the mouse events right now. I'm trying to use an Object of type Object and then redefine it's type depending on the type of Object that is clicked.

When I try this I get this error message :

Error   2   'object' does not contain a definition for 'setPosition' and no extension method 'setPosition' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I make it understand that the `selectedObject` has changed type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't "change the type" of an object, but that doesn't sound like what you want to do. It sounds like you have a value of a certain type that's held in a variable of type `object`.

In that case, you can just tell the compiler what the actual type of your value is using a "cast":

```
((Buoy)selectedObject).setPosition(mouseCurrentState.X - mouseStart.X, mouseCurrentState.Y - mouseStart.Y); 

(selectedObject as Buoy).setPosition(mouseCurrentState.X - mouseStart.X, mouseCurrentState.Y - mouseStart.Y);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried casting it as (Buoy)selectedObject before but I didn't think to put brackets around it. #dumb

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know in advance what kind (= C# class) of objects can be clicked on, e.g. A and B. Then in the event handler do something like this:

```
var a = selectedObject as A;
if (a != null)
{
  ...call some method of "a", e.g. setPosition...
  return;
}


var b = selectedObject as B;
if (b != null)
{
  ...call some method of "b", e.g. setPosition...
  return;
}
```

Comment: Yes there are only a few types that can be clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your code won't compile, because even if you know `Buoy` does indeed have a `setPosition` method, the fact you act upon it as an object shouldn't even let you compile.

What you want to do is just cast it to the type first.

```
internal void BuoyToMouse()
{
    object selectedObject;
    ChangeObjectType(typeof(Buoy), ref selectedObject);
    ((Buoy)selectedObject).setPosition(...
}
```

You will also want to use the ref keyword

```
public void ChangeObjectType(System.Type objectType, ref Object selectedObject)
{
    selectedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
}
```

As a note, this is not "changing" any types, you are creating a new instance of the Buoy class and using Activator to instantiate it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in C#. Smalltalk has this feature (become), but it is very uncommon.

What you are doing is to create a new instance in `ChangeObjectType` and the local parameter `selectedObject` points to this new instance. The local variable in `BuoyToMouse`is still pointing to the original instance.

It could work when using `ref` as a keyword for the parameter, but then you still need to cast the parameter after the message call to the new type.